How to use diesel embed_migrations? Getting "expected one of `!` or `::`"
I have a file structure as follows:
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── diesel.toml
├── migrations
│   └── 2024-11-14-193305_create_entities
│       ├── down.sql
│       └── up.sql
└── src
    └── main.rs

In my main.rs I have:
use diesel_migrations::embed_migrations;
embed_migrations!("migrations");

But it gives me an error:
error: expected one of `!` or `::`, found `(`
  --> src/main.rs:13:1
   |
13 | embed_migrations!("migrations");
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected one of `!` or `::`
   |
   = note: this error originates in the macro `embed_migrations` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

Any idea how can I proceed?

You appear to be using an older syntax for embed_migrations. If you are using the latest version you should instead use the macro to initialize a constant. Are you using version 1.x or 2.x?

Okay, I got it now. Yes, I was using latest version, but syntax was from previous version

I am using diesel_migration = "2.2.0" but was using the 1.0 syntax. The syntax for the new version should look like this:
use diesel_migrations::{embed_migrations, EmbeddedMigrations, MigrationHarness};
pub const MIGRATIONS: EmbeddedMigrations = embed_migrations!("migrations");

